# How can i get a input number value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers

I want to get the value of a input with the type of number. Here is the HTML

```html
<input type="number" id="number" value="1">
```

and here is the javasript

```js
const number = document.getElementById('number').value;
```

when i try to `console.log(number)` the result is `1` but when i increace the value of the input the result is still `1`.

When i want to `console.log(number)` i want the result to be `1` but when i increase the value of the input like `3` i want the result to be `3`.

Comment: You are incrementing a string?
Typecast it to number using +value or parseInt(value) and update the DOM on onChange using event listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to update the number when it changes. Consider adding an event listener to the input element. Such that it updates the number variable every time you change it's value.

```js
const numberInput = document.getElementById("number");
let number = numberInput.value;

numberInput.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
  number = event.target.value
  console.log(number)
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add a submit button to add it and use the following script:

```js
const numberInput = document.getElementById("number");
const buttonAdd = document.getElementById("add");
let number = numberInput.value;

buttonAdd.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  number = ++number;
  console.log(number);
  numberInput.value = number;
})
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" value="1"/>
<input type="submit" id="add" value="Add"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, all input field values are string, so

```js
const number = document.getElementById('number').value;
// number = "1"
```

Try adding `parseInt` to make it an integer:

```js
const number = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
// number = 1
```

Comment: If you're going to use `parseInt` [you should add in the radix parameter too](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description). Or use `Number(value)`, or `+value`.

Comment: @Andy You beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

You also have to update the DOM-element if you want to see the result.

```
const number = document.getElementById('number').value
number += 2
document.getElementById('number').value = number
```

Answer (score 0):

When you code:

```
const number_at_instant_time = document.getElementById('number').value;
```

You get **only** the string value **in** the input present at this moment.
if the input value change, the value `number_at_instant_time` will stay at the same value

so correct code should be:
[Coding also means reading up-to-date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

```js
const myNumber = document.querySelector('#my-number');

document.querySelector('#bt-get-num').onclick = () =>
  {
  console.clear();
  
  let strVal = myNumber.value;
  let numVal = myNumber.valueAsNumber;
  
  
  console.log('strVal + 15 = ', strVal + 15 )
  console.log('numVal + 15 = ', numVal + 15 )
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="my-number" value="1">
<br>
<button id="bt-get-num"> Get number value</button>
```